# XML for data modelling

Tags: xml, data-structures, data-modeling

is it possible to use XML format to define a data model that has various references? 
Ugh I realize that what I just wrote makes no sense. Let me explain. 
Suppose I have a model that represents a collection of points in the 3D space. Let's assume that some of these points have global coordinates, meaning that their x, y, z are just pure real numbers

```
<model>
   <point id="1" x="120" y="200" x="300" />
   <point id="2" x="40" y="-200" x="900" />
</model>
```

Everything good so far... Now let's suppose that another point, point 3 is depending on the position of point 1 and 2. For example it's located somewhere along the line that goes from point 1 to point 2.

```
<model>
   <point id="1" x="120" y="200" x="300" />
   <point id="2" x="40" y="-200" x="900" />
   <point id="3" x="??" y=""??" x="??" />
</model>
```

I know what those "??" represent. They represent the mid point. I can calculate that, but how can I express that in XML? Is there a way to define a function, say mid(point1, point2) and reference that in the XML file? How could I go about defining point id="3" as a function of other nodes in the XML document? (the other nodes are point id="1" and point id="2").

If anyone has a suggestion... there is so much information about XML format, being virtually used everywhere, that it's hard to navigate the amount of available info. 
Thanks!

Comment: XML is data. Period. Any behavior you want can only be achieved through the programs interpreting the data. You could, for example, add an element which is defined as midpoint of several points, rather than by absolute positions. Or permit simple expressions in addition to numbers in the attributes, and evaluate those. But you won't get `libxml2` to magically know that and do it too.

Answer (score 0):

Not possible.  XML syntax does not include any means to make the parser return the result of a calculation instead of data directly from the file.  In theory, you could come up with a way to express computations purely in XML like

```
<point id="3">
    <component id="x">
        <computation type="divide">
            <operand>
                <computation type="sum">
                    <operand>
                        <point_ref id="1" component="x">
                    </operand>
                    <operand>
                        <point_ref id="2" component="x">
                    </operand>
                </computation>
            </operand>
            <operand>
                2
            </operand>
        </computation>
    </component>
    ...
</point>
```

Wow, this seems like a lot of work.  I guess it might be useful though.

Comment: Programs ARE data.  Data that describe/define computational processes carried out by the computer.  Data that are fed to the compiler to produce the binaries that effectively carry out those computational processes.  Hence, XML can be used to store program code as well.  As your example demonstrates very nicely, BTW.  Your example is nothing more than an XML rendition of a piece of Abstract Syntax Tree.

Comment: I edited that sentence to better explain what I meant.  I thought about suggesting that the OP use S-Expressions instead :)